# How to create a mssql VIEW model using flask-migrate?

Tags: flask-migrate

Mssql+pyodbc connection.

Imports and db

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Table, text, Text, Unicode, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

I have generated table models using flask-sqlacodegen which look like this

```
class BlaBla(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bla_bla'

    blabla= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bla2= db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

The view that I have in the db was generated like this

```
t_bla_bla_bla_view = Table(
    'View_bla_bla_bla',
    Column('irrelevant', db.Unicode(50), nullable=False),
    Column('etc', db.Unicode(50), nullable=False),
    Column('etc2', db.Unicode(50), nullable=False)
)
```

When I run flask db migrate, the tables are properly created, while the View is also created as a table.
What is the actual syntax on creating a view?
Maybe there is a raw query migrate workaround?